# Cobordant to sphere or homotopy sphere

Tags: homotopy-theory, cobordism

In Ranicki's notes ([here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/books/surgery.pdf)) remark 6.19 distinguishes between cobordant to a sphere and cobordant to a homotopy sphere. Earlier in these notes right after example 1.6 he writes that homotopy equivalent closed manifolds are cobordant. Doesn't this mean that the two questions in remark 6.19 are the same question? If $M$ is cobordant to a sphere then the sphere is homotopy equivalent (cobordant) to a homotopy sphere so that $M$ is cobordant to a sphere if and only if it is cobordant to a homotopy spehre?

Comment: My guess is that yes, but that he did not prove that in the introduction, so one needs the distinction until one can prove that one no longer needs the distinction.